# OpenGL projects are looking for the libcxts.so library

Tags: linux, opengl, codeblocks, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to learn openGL for work, and for the life of me, I can't get it to work.  After a lot of work, I got my project to compile, but when I run it, I get an error stating:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcxts.so.2.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what this is.  I eventually found it in one of my openCV libraries, but that doesn't help me when it comes to programming in openGL (I don't even know where i should put it).

I'm working in Code Blocks, in Ubuntu 11 if that helps at all.

Comment: How do you build your project? What do you link to it?

Comment: Also, you may want to learn about the "accept answers" feature (the green checkmark beside answers to your questions). It is for answers that you feel best answer your question. You don't seem to have used it much.

Comment: It had something to do with code blocks.  OpenCV was not involved in the opengl program.  I even tried compiling one of my proven OpenCV programs, along with the standard hello world and same issue.  I fixed it by reinstalling codeblocks.

Answer (score 2):

It's openCV's code testing lib (or at least that's one of it's uses - perhaps other projects have used the same naming)

Are you using openCV ?